# How to create a trail effect in a rendertexture?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a cumulative trail effect in a render texture. By cumulative I mean that the render texture would show the last few frames overlaid on each other. Currently, when my camera outputs to a render texture it completely overwrites whatever was there previously.

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/03/09/simulate-smoke-with-shaders/

Comment: @mgear Oh, this looks like a step in the right direction. I'm going to study the shader and see if I can adapt it to what I'm doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the clear flag on the camera to Don't clear. This will prevent the clearing of previous frame on your camera and then will create this overlapping kinda like Flash movement style.

The issue is that everything will be kept on screen so if only the character moves then it is ok but if the camera moves then the effect also applies to environment and your scene becomes a big blur.

You could have two cameras for the effect, each with different rendering layers. One takes care of the items that should not have the effect and one takes care of those that are considered for the effect. This way you can apply the effect on characters and ignore the environment, if that is required else just go with one camera.

Comment: Hm, are you sure this works with a render texture? If I add a render texture to a camera with the clear flag set to Don't Clear, the effect you described isn't reflected in the render texture.

Comment: I would guess since your render texture is meant to render whatever the camera is displaying but you seem to tell that it does not. What do you get on teh texture with Don't clear set?